# What is the name of the resulting function?

Tags: regression, function, likelihood

Consider the following population regression model:

$$y_{i} = \beta _{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i} + \epsilon _{i},$$

where $i=1,...,n$. Assume $\epsilon \sim iid$, with the pdf in equation: $f(\epsilon ) = \alpha \epsilon$ for $0\leq \epsilon \leq 1$.

For $n=4$, we have $f(\epsilon _{1},\epsilon _{2},\epsilon _{3},\epsilon _{4}) = f_{1}(\epsilon _{1}) f_{2}(\epsilon _{2}) f_{3}(\epsilon _{3}) f_{4}(\epsilon _{4}) = \alpha \prod _{i=1}^{4} \epsilon _{i}$. This is because of no autocorrelation in errors.

Now we substitute $f(\epsilon _{1},\epsilon _{2},\epsilon _{3},\epsilon _{4})$ in the regression model and obtain

$$y_{i} = \beta _{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i}+\prod _{i=1}^{4} \epsilon _{i}$$.

Taking the natural logs, we obtain

$$ln(y_{i}) = ln(\beta _{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i}+\prod _{i=1}^{4} \epsilon _{i})$$.

What is a common name for the resulting function?

I am guessing it is the maximum log likelihood function. Am I correct?

Comment: Are you sure you're typing the question right?

Comment: Much of this makes no sense. You seem to be trying to write down a likelihood, but do not succeed due to a sequence of errors.  Asking for the name of the resulting (meaningless) expression seems beside the point.  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to say, but this is a totally confused mix up.

First, it appears that $f(\epsilon)$ is a probability density function. If this is the case it must intagrate to unity, over the specified domain of the variable. So we must have

$$\int_0^1 \alpha \epsilon d\epsilon = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{\alpha}{2}\epsilon^2|_0^1 = 1 \Rightarrow \alpha =2$$

Second, we do *not* insert the joint density of the four independent errors (they must be independent, not just non-autocorrelated) into the functional specification of the regression. What we do to arrive at the maximum likelihood estimator is to note that from the regression specification we obtain by solving for $\epsilon$,

$$y_{i} - \beta _{1} - \beta_{2}x_{i} = \epsilon _{i}$$

and substitute this into the joint probability density

$$L = \prod_{i=1}^4I_{\{\epsilon_i \in [0,1]\}}\cdot f(\epsilon_i) =  \prod_{i=1}^4\alpha I_{\{y_{i} - \beta _{1} - \beta_{2}x_{i} \in [0,1]\}} \cdot \left(y_{i} - \beta _{1} - \beta_{2}x_{i}\right)$$

Note the inclusion of the indicator function that expresses the restriction on the support of $\epsilon_i$.

The log-likelihood is

$$\ln L = 4\ln2 + \sum_{i=1}^4\ln\left(y_{i} - \beta _{1} - \beta_{2}x_{i}\right) + \sum_{i=1}^4\ln I_{\{y_{i} - \beta _{1} - \beta_{2}x_{i} \in [0,1]\}}$$

The last term is translated into $2n$ inequality restrictions when we move to solve the above maximization problem with respect to the parameters, of the form

$$y_{i} - \beta _{1} - \beta_{2}x_{i} \geq 0,\;\;\; y_{i} - \beta _{1} - \beta_{2}x_{i} \leq 1$$
for each $i$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I didn't understand the instructions properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this version of the log likelihood is also incorrect.  It is essential to incorporate the fact that the distribution is supported on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: @whuber I will update after I finish another answer I am writing, but you know as well as I do that we tend to consider the support as "understood" (and it is not the only bad practice we follow).

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I have questions about the same model, which you might be interested in taking a look http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122860/inference-about-the-true-intercept-of-the-model-and-the-ols-being-blue. Again thanks for the update.

Comment: @Alecos I'm not trying to be picky here. I pointed out that error because it has been the cause of *many* posts on this site concerning problems with ML. If you consider what might happen were someone to implement your (original) formula in software, you would immediately see the difficulty: it may try to take logarithms of negative numbers and, if it overcomes that difficulty, it will eventually produce near-infinite estimates of the coefficients.

Comment: @whuber You' right. I hope now it is ok.